# Set FlashMode on Windows Phone 8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera

I'm making my first camera app. I'm trying to set the flash mode with this line of code:

```
 camera.SetProperty(KnownCameraPhotoProperties.FlashMode, FlashMode.Auto);
```

but I get this exception: 
ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range
I've also tried to check the availability of the Flash but the result doesn't change

```
var supportedFlashModes = PhotoCaptureDevice.GetSupportedPropertyValues(CameraSensorLocation.Back, KnownCameraPhotoProperties.FlashMode);
            if (supportedFlashModes.ToList().Contains((UInt32)FlashMode.Auto))
            {
                camera.SetProperty(KnownCameraPhotoProperties.FlashMode, FlashMode.Auto);
            }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
camera.SetProperty(KnownCameraPhotoProperties.FlashMode, FlashState.Auto);
```

and it will work. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662940(v=vs.105).aspx for more details.